# Tkinter Treeview Runs off Main Window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview, tkinter-layout

I am trying to create a Treeview with a variable number of columns that allows for horizontal scrolling when the number of columns makes the TreeView wider than the main window. Right now I have both a vertical and horizontal scrollbar implemented. The horizontal scrollbar is never enabled because the TreeView and Frame containing it both expand to fit all of the columns, with the excess running off the main window. However, the height of the TreeView doesn't change, regardless of the number of rows. If someone could help me mimic that behavior for the horizontal, it would be greatly appreciated.

**TreeView too Big, can't see Vertical Scrollbar or right end of horizontal scrollbar**
[image: TreeView too Big, can't see Vertical Scrollbar or right end of horizontal scrollbar]

**TreeView fits, both scrollbars can be seen**
[image: TreeView fits, both scrollbars can be seen]

**I've tried to include the relevant code below:**

```
class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.dora = DoraExplorer()

    self.currentDict = {}
    self.lbox_list = []
    self.prevIndex =''
    self.pack()
    self.create_widgets()

def populateTreeView(self,tabDict):
    header = tabDict['header']
    data = tabDict['data']
    self.tree["columns"] = header
    self.tree['show'] = 'headings'
    self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

    for head in header:
        self.tree.column(head, width=10, anchor='c')
        self.tree.heading(head, text=head)
    #print(data)
    for j in range(len(data)):
        row = list(data[j])
        self.tree.insert("",'end',text=str(j),values=row)

def queryAction(self):
    #self.frame.delete('1.0',END)
    d = self.dbVar.get()
    t = self.tableVar
    cf = self.query.get()
    queryResults = self.dora.runQueries(cf,d,t)

    queryText = queryResults['text']
    label = queryText['label']
    title = queryText['title']


    self.populateTreeView(queryResults['table'])
def create_widgets(self):

    self.query = StringVar()
    self.createDBMenu()
    self.search_var = StringVar()
    self.search_var.trace("w", self.update_list)
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
    self.lbox = Listbox(self, width=45, height=15,yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.lbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',self.onselect)
    self.lbox.grid(row=4, column=1,rowspan=9, padx=10, pady=3)

    self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.search_var, width=40)
    self.entry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

    self.cRadio = Radiobutton(self,text='Count',variable=self.query,value ='countTop',indicatoron=0)
    self.cRadio.grid(row=13,column=1)

    self.fRadio = Radiobutton(self,text='Foreign',variable=self.query,value ='foreignKeys',indicatoron=0)
    self.fRadio.grid(row=14,column=1)

    self.queryButton = Button(self, text="Query", command=self.queryAction)
    self.queryButton.grid(row=9,column=2,padx=3,pady=.05)

    self.treeFrame = Frame(self,width = 300, height = 400)
    self.treeFrame.grid(row=4, column=3,columnspan=3,rowspan=9, padx=10, pady=3)
    self.treeFrame.columnconfigure(3,weight=1)

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.treeFrame, selectmode='browse')
    self.tree.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NSEW,in_=self.treeFrame, columnspan=3, rowspan=9)
    self.tree.grid_propagate(False)
    self.scbHDirSel =Scrollbar(self.treeFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.tree.xview)
    self.scbVDirSel =Scrollbar(self.treeFrame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
    self.scbVDirSel.grid(row=1, column=50, rowspan=50, sticky=NS, in_=self.treeFrame)
    self.scbHDirSel.grid(row=52, column=0, rowspan=2,columnspan=3, sticky=EW,in_=self.treeFrame)
    self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scbVDirSel.set, xscrollcommand=self.scbHDirSel.set) 

root = Tk()

root.title("Tk dropdown example")

app= Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up switching to wxPython as their Grid class does this natively

[SimpleGrid](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/Simplegrid.htm)